# Attempting to have a group of units create random values independently in python 3 for a salvage loot system

Tags: python

I am working on creating a salvage mechanic for my game.  I want different units to calculate salvage after an encounter to randomly determine how much each one was able to scavenge from fallen allies or attackers.

As I have it setup up now its calculate as a group.
IE:  If I have group of units whom collectively can salvage value of 5 and for each point of salvage I can potentially gain 1-4 piece of salvage then I have a range of 5-20 pieces of salvage (provided there are 20 or more pieces of salvage to collect).  I am simply multiplying the total salvage value of the group by a randomly determined number in a range of 1-4.

My question is, how can I get each unit to calculate its salvage individually from its own range, rather than as a group as I'm doing now to give greater variance in the amount of salvage generated?

I am rather new and any suggestion or insight would be appreciated.

Below is the code for a demo I setup for the salvage system:

```
import random

parts_inventory = 0
undif_unit_count = 999
haulers = 2
foragers = 1
salvage_value = (haulers * 2) + foragers
temp_salvage = 0
salvage_random = random.randint(1, 4)

attack = random.randint(1, 6)
fatalities = attack
salvage_pool = fatalities * 4

print("There were {} units destroyed resulting in {} pieces of potential salvage".format(attack, salvage_pool))
print("Your units can haul away {} peice of salvage".format(salvage_value))


def salvage_operation(parts_inventory=parts_inventory):
    print("Encounter Haul {}".format(salvage_value))
    if salvage_value <= salvage_pool:
        print("You gained {} salvaged parts.".format(salvage_value))
        parts_inventory = parts_inventory + salvage_value
    if salvage_value > salvage_pool:
        print("You gained {} salvaged parts.".format(salvage_pool))
        parts_inventory = parts_inventory + salvage_pool
salvage_operation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not how you would normally write Python

```
from random import randint

def units_scrap_rolls(current_salvage, haulers, foragers):
  rolls = [(haulers, 6), (foragers, 4)]  
  for unit_count, roll_max in rolls:
    for i in range(unit_count):
      current_salvage += randint(1, 6)
  return current_salvage

salvage
salvage = print(units_scrap_rolls(salvage, 2, 1))
print(salvage)
```

- Notice the function has a return value
- Using Python range() instead of while
- Concise code
- No default values for the variables if they aren't used

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I managed to come up with after talking with a friend involving making a function to essentially roll dice for each unit via a loop.

```
import random

haulers = 2
foragers = 1
temp_salvage = 0
count = 0

def units_scrap_rolls(temp_salvage=temp_salvage, haulers=haulers, foragers=foragers, count=count):
    if haulers > 0:
        number_of_rolls = haulers
        count = number_of_rolls
        while number_of_rolls >= count and count > 0:
            temp_salvage = temp_salvage + random.randint(1, 6)
            count = count - 1
        print ("After the Haulers were done, you had {} salvage.".format(temp_salvage))
    if foragers > 0:
        number_of_rolls = foragers
        count = number_of_rolls
        while number_of_rolls >= count and count > 0:
            temp_salvage = temp_salvage + random.randint(1, 4)
            count = count - 1

    print("In total you gained {} pieces of salvage.".format(temp_salvage))

units_scrap_rolls()
```